# Embedding Stack Overflow answers into my website?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm looking for a way to embed [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery/15747224#15747224) into my blog, as [I embed my JSfiddle into a blog](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html#tutorial).

Is there an API to embed Stack Overflow's answers or questions?

---

**Edit:** the JSfiddle syntaxe to embed a fiddle is as easy as the single line :

```
<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/F26ur/embedded/result,js,html,css/" 
style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
```

StackTack needs 12 lines of code.

Comment: Embedded I don't know but: http://stackapps.com/about

Comment: Even better: http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere

Answer (score 17):

Just use [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere), which is the highest upvoted application on StackApps.com. Looks like [there's also a WordPress plugin for it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stacktack/) (assuming you use WordPress).

Here is a screenshot of it in action:

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Looks like <del>someone in the comments</del> [cheesemacfly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208062/cheesemacfly) beat me to it.

Comment: What if we no use WordPrez

Comment: @ColeJohnson Then use the Javascript thing. I was saying there's also a WordPress plugin for it.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't read fully...

Comment: Am I wrong or it needs 12 lines of code ? Not really a shortcut.

Comment: You are wrong. You already have a `head` part of your code, may or may not already use jQuery (if you do, you don't need that line), and you already have a `<body>` All you need to do is add this to your `<head>`: `<script src="http://app.stacktack.com/jquery.stacktack.min.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(function(){$(document).stacktack();});</script>` and then add this where you want it: `<div id="stacktack-518021"></div>` It really isn't that much, and as I said, there is a WordPress plugin for it if that's what you use. The only other way short of writing your own script is an iframe

Answer (score 2):

I have created another solution for embedding stack overflow code in websites.

I have wrapped the API with components / directive (not all, but tell me what else you need and I will create it for you, and all the stack overflow community), this is enables you to use it like a tag in your html.

Here is a page that I made to explain it a bit more:

http://weldpad.com/?containerId=59814#/stackover

And here is a live sample:
http://weldpad.com/?containerId=47901&editcontainer=61028

In all the samples you can copy the code to your html (or even copy it to notepad and save as html), and just run it, It should work.
If not please tell me.

Regards
Dan.

Comment: dead url. Not able to preview or see the content anymore